# SapUI5 Smart table expand: Filter/ Sorter / Group a column of 'Expand'

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to use smart table expand but I can't filter the column of Collection Entity.

[image]

Controller.js

```
onBeforeRebind: function(oEvent) {
  var mBindingParams = oEvent.getParameter("bindingParams");
  mBindingParams.parameters["expand"] = " T006Details";
}
```

Filter / Sorter / Group:

[image]

Result:
[image]

Could you give me some advice, please?

Comment: Could you see the data in the expand column?

Comment: Yes, I see the data in the expand column, but when I filter or sorter, there isn't data...

Comment: modify the filter in beforeBinding event of the smart table.